# Kitten Diarrhea With Blood

Tags: cats, health

I have 2 1/2 months old male persian kitten. It is not still dewormed , bought it a month ago , came to know about deworming few days ago . Whenever I feed cat food, changed the cat food too, kitten has blood in its stool and has diarrhea . Whenever i stop feeding cat food, diarrhea is better than before . Is this the problem in dry foods ? I also came to know that diarrhea and blood in stool is also caused by parasites / worms. Someone told me that it is also because of stress, but kittens seems to be fine to me .

Comment: Visit a vet asap

Comment: your cat have to go to a vet,and i think you have to ask a vet about some of your questions.

Comment: I also think a vet should take a look, it may be as simple as the changes in food but blood in stool should never be ignored.

Comment: start by worming the cat asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question as it may help someone else too.

Kitten diarrhea was fixed by stop feeding boiled chicken daily and feeding dry cat food as a regular diet.

Secondly, the blood was stopped by deworming the kitten.